# HPC Pack 2016: "Identity check failed for outgoing message" Error

Tags: windows, wcf, dns, mpi, hpc

Hello Stack Overflow community, I am encountering the following errors when I try to add a node to my local computer cluster using Microsoft HPC Pack 2016:

- > Could not contact node 'NODE-A08' to perform change. Identity check
  >   failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote
  >   endpoint was 'HEAD-NODE01' but the remote endpoint provided DNS claim
  >   'NODE-A08'. If this is a legitimate remote endpoint, you can fix the
  >   problem by explicitly specifying DNS identity 'NODE-A08' as the
  >   Identity property of EndpointAddress when creating channel proxy.
- > Could not contact node 'NODE-A08' to perform change. The management
  >   service was unable to connect to the node using any of the IP
  >   addresses resolved for the node.

Ultimately I would like to write and test my own MPI programs while using HPC Pack as my cluster manager, but I cannot seem to get past this preliminary step of setting up my cluster.

Through my research in to the issue I have found "Identity check failed for outgoing message..." to be a well documented error related to Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). My understanding is that it occurs when the common name (CN) of the endpoint computer's certificate does not match its DNS identity.

The solutions that I found where lines of code for people writing their own programs, however those solutions do not apply to HPC Pack because I cannot access its source code directly.

Some additional information specific to my situation:

- the certificates used by both the head node and the node were issued
  individually by a trusted domain
- all computers are connect to one enterprise network
- the head node's PC name is 'HEAD-NODE01'
- the node's PC name is 'NODE-A08'
- these errors occur during the provisioning stage of adding a node
- the errors are displayed in the provisioning log within HPC Pack
  2016's user interface
- I was successful in pinging each computer from the other
- both computers display the proper DNS IP address when I use command
  prompt
- the head node is running Windows Server 2012 R2
- the node is preconfigured to be a workstation node and is running
  Windows 10 Enterprise

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have looked for a few days and in a lot of places for an answer, but I have not been very successful. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Subject names of both SSL certificates must be identical